# Php Variable not working in UPLOAD script

Tags: php

I have the following script:

```
<?php

$userid = $_GET['user'];

// A list of permitted file extensions
$allowed = array('png', 'jpg', 'gif','zip');

if(isset($_FILES['upl']) && $_FILES['upl']['error'] == 0){

    $extension = pathinfo($_FILES['upl']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

    if(!in_array(strtolower($extension), $allowed)){
        echo '{"status":"error"}';
        exit;
    }


    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['upl']['tmp_name'], '../../'.$userid.'/assets/'.$_FILES['upl']['name'])){ 

        echo '{"status":"success"}';
        echo ' '.$userid;
        exit;
    }
}

echo '{"status":"error"}';
echo ' '.$userid;
exit;

?>
```

The problem is in this line:

```
    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['upl']['tmp_name'], '../../'.$userid.'/assets/'.$_FILES['upl']['name'])){
```

When I use this path - everything works fine and the upload is successful:

```
'../../assets/'.$_FILES['upl']['name']
```

or

```
'../assets/'.$_FILES['upl']['name']
```

or

```
'assets/'.$_FILES['upl']['name']
```

All of these three work fine - but when I add the VARIABLE from a GET (from the URL path), it does not work? I know the VARIABLE "userid" is being recognized because I am echoing out before and after the path and it displays on the screen. Also I DID set write permissions on all of the folders, as defined by the VARIABLE.

Any thoughts?

THIS WAS ADDED >>>>>> THIS IS THE FIRST FILE....

```
<?

$userid = $_GET['user'];

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8"/>
        <title>Mini Ajax File Upload Form</title>

        <!-- Google web fonts -->
        <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Sans+Narrow:400,700" rel='stylesheet' />

        <!-- The main CSS file -->
        <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    </head>

    <body>
    <p style="text-align:center"><? echo $userid; ?></p>

        <form id="upload" method="post" action="upload.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <div id="drop">
                Drop Here

                <a>Browse</a>
                <input type="file" name="upl" multiple />
            </div>

            <ul>
                <!-- The file uploads will be shown here -->
            </ul>

        </form>


        <!-- JavaScript Includes -->
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/jquery.knob.js"></script>

        <!-- jQuery File Upload Dependencies -->
        <script src="js/jquery.ui.widget.js"></script>
        <script src="js/jquery.iframe-transport.js"></script>
        <script src="js/jquery.fileupload.js"></script>

        <!-- Our main JS file -->
        <script src="js/script.js"></script>


    </body>
</html>
```

THIS IS THE PROCESSING FILE....

```
<?php

$userid = $_GET['user'];

// A list of permitted file extensions
$allowed = array('png', 'jpg', 'gif','zip');

if(isset($_FILES['upl']) && $_FILES['upl']['error'] == 0){

    $extension = pathinfo($_FILES['upl']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

    if(!in_array(strtolower($extension), $allowed)){
        echo '{"status":"error"}';
        exit;
    }

    // if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['upl']['tmp_name'], '../../'.$userid.'/assets/'.$_FILES['upl']['name'])){  
    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['upl']['tmp_name'], '../../'.$userid.'/assets/'.$_FILES['upl']['name'])){ 

        echo '{"status":"success"}';
        echo ' '.$userid;
        exit;
    }
}

echo '{"status":"error"}';
echo ' '.$userid;
exit;

?>
```

Comment: BYW this is the script as found here: http://demo.tutorialzine.com/2013/05/mini-ajax-file-upload-form/      (I was simply trying to add a dynamic variable)

Comment: how is it not working? you should be getting error messages

Comment: need to see the HTML form for this and how that GET array is being accessed. In the meantime, add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything.

Comment: Is the folder `'../../'.$userid.` been created

Comment: If you have access to a shell run "ls -la ../../$userid" within the directory where the script resides (replacing the UID with the real name)

Comment: "how is it not working" - It is not placing the file in the directory - Code Below...

Comment: Did you create the directory for that user? You have to create the directory first, and then move your files to it - it won't be created automatically.

Comment: below the ocean waves, i'll go check SpongeBob's house

Comment: @Dagon that's where the guessworks starts. pass the popcorn

Comment: i still don't see how $userid is ever passed

Comment: @Dagon not even a guess? come come now... surely you jest.

Comment: @Fred-ii- i guess it's tattooed on the side of the unicorn that is then sent to the code planet by the enterprises transporter

Comment: @Dagon yeah, it passed by my house last night.

Comment: well never mind error reporting; it won't serve you.

Comment: op - test this, hard code the user id`$userid = $_GET['user'];` change to `$userid = 99;` or a known id - then file upload, does that work or fail ?

Comment: *"but when I add the VARIABLE from a GET (from the URL path)"* - then, you need to show us that. You probably may get away with it by passing that path and variable to the action in your form. Other than that; I have no idea, because you're leaving out a very important piece of the puzzle.

Comment: *"[But it needs to be dynamic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30609522/php-variable-not-working-in-upload-script#comment49286558_30609592)"* - ouh, now that's broad. Hey @Dagon can you define "dynamic" for me? In less than 3 words please.

Comment: @Fred-ii- verily versatile variable .

Comment: @Dagon I wasn't very good with [**puzzles**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30609522/php-variable-not-working-in-upload-script#comment49286562_30609522) myself. but thanks :-)

Answer (score 0):

Unless you're creating a subdirectory in `../../`  for each and every user manually, you need to create the directory for that user before trying to move the files to it.

```
if(!file_exist("../../$userid/")
    mkdir("../../$userid/");
```

... and then you can move your file to it.

Comment: Yes - all of the subdirectories are already created and named - it is simply not putting the uploads in the designated path (directory name/assets)

Comment: INTERESTING - if I hard code the directory name - IT WORKS ? Im not sure how this is even possible -- But it needs to be dynamic...